# How to compare multiple values in one column against a delimited string in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, arrays, stored-procedures

Ok, first question, and you guys scare me with how much you know, so please be gentle...

I am trying to pass in a delimited string and convert it to an array in a stored procedure and then use the array to check against values in a column. Here's the catch. I'm trying to take the preexisting table, that checks for one association and expand it to allow for multiple associations.

So the column annAssociations might have three ids, 4,16,32, but I need to check if it belongs to the groupIds being queried, 6,12,32. Since one of the values matched, it should return that row.

Here is the procedure as it exists.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_annList] 
-- Date Range of Announcements.
@dateBegin datetime,
@dateEnd datetime,
    -- Announcement type and associations.
@annType varchar(50),
@annAssociation varchar(255)

AS
BEGIN

-- Set the SELECT statement for the announcements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- See if this should be a limited query
IF @annAssociation <> ''
    Begin
        SELECT * 
        FROM announcements
        WHERE (date1 <= @dateEnd AND date2 >= @dateBegin) -- See if the announcement falls in the date range.
            AND annType = @annType -- See if the announcement is the right type.
            AND annAssociations LIKE (select SplitText from dbo.fnSplit(@annAssociation, ','))
        ORDER BY title
    END
Else 
    Begin
        SELECT *
        FROM announcements
        WHERE (date1 <= @dateEnd AND date2 >= @dateBegin)
            AND annType = @annType
        ORDER BY title
    End
END
```

And here is the method I'm using to convert the delimited string and store it in a temporary table.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[fnSplit](@text text, @delimitor nchar(1))

RETURNS
@table TABLE
(
[Index] int Identity(0,1),
[SplitText] varchar(10)
)
AS

BEGIN
declare @current varchar(10)
declare @endIndex int
declare @textlength int
declare @startIndex int

set @startIndex = 1

if(@text is not null)
begin
    set @textLength = datalength(@text)

    while(1=1)
    begin
        set @endIndex = charindex(@delimitor, @text, @startIndex)

        if(@endIndex != 0)
        begin
            set @current = substring(@text,@startIndex, @endIndex - @StartIndex)
            Insert Into @table ([SplitText]) values(@current)
            set @startIndex = @endIndex + 1   
        end
        else
        begin
            set @current = substring(@text, @startIndex, datalength(@text)-@startIndex+1)
            Insert Into @table ([SplitText]) values(@current)
            break
        end
    end

end

return
END
```

Sorry for the long question. I just wanted to get all the info out there. I've been researching for days, and I either don't know where to look or am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't get much better performance than this approach (well you might see better performance with a CLR split function but at 3 or 4 items you won't see much difference):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM announcements AS a
  WHERE ...
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.fnSplit(@annAssociation) AS n
    WHERE ',' + a.annList + ',' LIKE '%,' + n.SplitText + ',%');
```

The key here is that you only need to split up one of the lists.

You *really* should stop storing multiple values in the `annAssocations` column. Each id is a separate piece of data and should be stored separately (in addition to better conforming to normalization, it will make queries like this simpler).

Comment: I know. The db was originally set up with only one association, and then some idiot had the bright idea to have multiples associations. That was me of course. My plan is to go back and redo the whole structure when there isn't a time crunch. I might end up going back anyway. What's a few more hours in the middle of the night... Thanks for the help. That gets me going.