# Sql to compare a delimited string against known table of values to find mismatches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will check if a string contains values that are in another table.

I am not in control of TableA and the data stored in this theoretical Packages column is a delimited set of words.

To demonstrate, TableA contains a column, Packages. This column contains a caret-delimited string of package, E.G `A^B` would mean that this row has 2 packages.

TableB is a table I control that lists the available packages.

As we can see, TableA has some rows that does not have a corresponding package; `D` for example.

TableA

```
ID  |  Packages
============
1   |  A
2   |  A^B
3   |  C
4   |  A^B
5   |  A^C
6   |  D
7   |  C^D
```

TableB

```
ID  |  Package
============
91  |  A
92  |  B
93  |  C
```

I am trying to write a script that will compare the packages in TableA against the known list of Package in TableB and select any row from TableA that does not have a supporting package.

Once ran, I am aiming to return a result similar to this,

```
TableAID  |  PackageNotSupported
================================
6         |  D
7         |  D
```

I can't really show what I have tried so far because I just do not know where to start. I have a function in the database that will split a delimited string into a table. I can use this against the `xx^xx^xx` data but i can't figure out at all how to join/compare the strings.

I tried the solution found in this post, [How to compare multiple values in one column against a delimited string in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988846/how-to-compare-multiple-values-in-one-column-against-a-delimited-string-in-a-sto) but could not get the result i was aiming for. Ultimately SQL is not my strong suit and i don't have the greatest understanding of the solution proposed in that post.

Comment: is the ID column unique in both tables?

Comment: Ref the close-vote. What other site in the network would you like me to put this programming question?

Comment: @scsimon- yes, the ID is unique in both tables. I will amend the Q to reflect this and remove any confusion

Comment: Why do people get offended about close vote proposals? I thought it was advanced enough to be asked on dba.se, that's all. As you were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - Without a Parse/Split Function**

```
Declare @TableA table (ID int,Packages varchar(25))
Insert Into @TableA values
(1   ,'A'),
(2   ,'A^B'),
(3   ,'C'),
(4   ,'A^B'),
(5   ,'A^C'),
(6   ,'D'),
(7   ,'C^D')

Declare @TableB table (ID int,Package varchar(25))
Insert Into @TableB values
(1   ,'A'),
(2   ,'B'),
(3   ,'C')


Select A.ID
      ,Package=B.RetVal 
 From  @TableA A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Packages,'^','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Left Join @TableB C on B.RetVal=C.Package
 Where  C.Package is null
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Package
6   D
7   D
```

**Option 2 - With a Parse/Split Function**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Package=B.RetVal 
 From  @TableA A
 Cross Apply  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Packages,'^') B
 Left Join @TableB C on B.RetVal=C.Package
 Where  C.Package is null
```

**The Parse UDF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Comment: Holy crap! I tried all of those, sans the udf-str-parse as I can use our split-string-into-a-table function. They all work wonderfully. I'll go read up on `cross apply` so i have some idea of what i'm copy/pasting :) Thanks John.

Comment: @Darren Happy it helped

Comment: @Darren CROSS APPLY is a very powerful feature.  Think of it as a sub-routine.  In this case, we expand your single record into multiple

Comment: @Darren Just for a better visual. Change the query to Select * and remove the WHERE